# Problem importing amplify into my project

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, config, node-modules, aws-amplify

When I try to import amplify as follows:

```js
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify'
import awsmobile from './aws-exports'
Amplify.configure(awsmobile)
```

it generates the following error:

> ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/geo/node_modules/camelcase-keys/index.js
> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (33:2)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> |       deep: false,
> |       pascalCase: false,
> |       ...options
> |   };

I am not using webpack in my project

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution? I have the same problem on web, on iOS it works.